# Why isn't my mobile website auto-resizing for mobile devices?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've upgraded from jQuery Mobile a3 to b1, (Mainly because a3 didn't work with WP7 devices) and now it's not scaling correctly on any of my devices (iPhone 4, Droid X, HTC Surround - WP7).  Any idea's as to what's causing this? I'm not using any custom css or anything else special... (I was previously, but I've since removed it all in attempt to find out what was causing the issue)

It does re-size with chrome when I re-size the window. I've tried clearing the cache/cookies/history/everything on the phones.

http://us.parkmobile.com/mobile/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your not setting the viewpoint meta tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/ (right click to view source)

Comment: When did they start requiring this? It used to not be required... (when I switched back to a3, it worked fine.

Comment: Well spotted! +2 if it was allowed

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

This is what I use :-)